# How could "Crash your favorite compiler" be edited to be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, challenges, specific-question, closed-questions

I recently found the closed [Crash your favorite compiler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7197/19617) question and was wondering how a type of question like this could be changed to fit the requirements of a challenge question as outlined in the Help Center.

Could we break it down into "crash your favorite IDE" vs "crash your favorite compiler?"  What about crashes related to memory corruption or crashes not found by fuzzing?  Would any of these contestants make this question on-topic?

Comment: "Too broad" can be confusing/misleading. It's using pop-con as an excuse for having no specification. What counts as a right answer, what counts as wrong? The "what makes one answer better than another" _may_ be subjective, but it doesn't exist leading to it's close

Comment: @Upgoat so would specifying to crash an interpreter or compiler itself (without maxing out the machine's RAM or something like that) be enough to make the question appropriate for a code challenge?

Comment: The main problem with editing the challenge in these ways would be that most of the answers would be invalidated, and have to be deleted by mods. A decent way to approach this might be to sandbox a say code golf challenge with a much more rigorous validity criterion.